# Unable to return image stream from action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, stream

I have the following action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string path)
{
     StaticImage image = await _images.UseRepositoryAsync(repo => repo.ReadAsync(path));
     return image != null ? new FileStreamResult(image.Stream, "image/jpeg") : (ActionResult)HttpNotFound();
}
```

I have a generic persistence strategy (uses Amazon S3) that retrieves `StaticImage` as follows:

```
//E is StaticImage in this case
//The returned entity is not disposed, it leaves that responsability to the controller
//However, the response IS disposed, that's why I need to copy the stream
public async Task<E> SelectAsync(params object[] keys)
{
     using(GetObjectResponse response = await MakeGetObjectRequestAsync(keys.First().ToString()))
     {
           if(response == null) return default(E);

           E entity = CreateEntity();
           entity.Key = response.Key;

           Stream entityStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.ToInt32(response.ResponseStream.Length));
           await response.ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(entityStream);
           entity.Stream = entityStream; 

           return entity;
     }
}
```

`response.ResponseStream` contains the image's content:

[image]

And it is being copied just fine to the new stream (see `Length`):

[image]

However, `0` bytes are returned from my controller:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at your second image, the stream's position is `197397`. My assumption is that when you're passing it to the constructor of `FileStreamResult`, it's not copying it because the position is at the end of the stream. Before you pass it to the constructor of `FileStreamResult`, set the position back to 0:

```
StaticImage image = await _images.UseRepositoryAsync(repo => repo.ReadAsync(path));     
image.Stream.Position = 0;
return image != null ? new FileStreamResult(image.Stream, "image/jpeg") : (ActionResult)HttpNotFound();
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe this was the issue! :P

Comment: @MatiCicero no problem. It's a common issue when working with streams.