# Display user profile picture in navbar in .net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I have the following logic to return an image store in wwwroot folder. Each time Url.Action Calls the Action method in the controller it returns a user image if exists else blank image. How do you return the physical image path result to Url.Action from the controller? Any help would be much appreciated. What method is used to return the physical image path?

**This is my User Image Code on Navbar Razor Pages (CSHTML):**

```
<img class="rounded-circle me-1" src="@Url.Action("MyProfilePic", "MyProfile")" height="24" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

**Controller Action Method: (.NET Core)**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyProfilePic()
{
    var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var profilPicName = user.ProfilePicName;
    if (profilPicName != null)
    {
    var ext = ".jpg";
    string fullname = Path.Combine(profilPicName,ext) ;
    string profilePicPath = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", fullname);
    return profilePicPath //Full path of image
    }
    return //Path of the ImagePlaceholder
}
```

Comment: If you can be sure the image exists, then a simple `<img src="~/images/@Model.UserProfileImage">` - if you need to check if it exists first, then probably the easiest way is to check the file system in the action and change Model.UserProfileImage to "default.jpg".   Alternatively, point your image to an Action and have that action determine which image to use - this would be quicker as it moves the disk access out of the main Action, eg:  `<img src='@Url.Action("GetUserProfileImage")'>` to return the path, but requires two hits, so you could return a `data:` object instead.

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m Thanks for the reponse. The issue is that my Navbar is in _layout shared view which I cannot tie to a Model. Then I could have used /@Model.UserProfileImage, but this is not possible.

The second option that you have suggested seems a viable solution. If you could elaborate on the how to use url.Action Method would me much help.

Comment: How do you know who the user is in the layout?  Something like `<img src="~/images/@User.Identify.GetUser()">` then store your images by id.

Comment: There's plenty of solutions already on SO to [return image data from an action](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net-mvc%5D+return+image+from+action), eg [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635421/unable-to-return-image-stream-from-action-in-asp-net-mvc) shows how to do it more-or-less (return a `FileStreamResult`)

Comment: @freedomn-m To retreive using /@Url.Action I can have a method in my controller to provide file path result each time Url.Action is called. This method will also get the current signed in user.

public async Task<IActionResult> MyProfilePic()
  {
   var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   var profilPicName = user.ProfilePicName;
   if (profilPicName != null)
   {
    return ViewBag.ProfilePicName = profilPicName;
   }
   return ViewBag.ProfilePicName;
  }

Comment: @freedomn-m In other words how do I return a URL from my MyProfilePic Method for /@Url.Action in .net core

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks man! I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long day here is the solution for those looking for the same.

**Image Tag:**

```
<img class="rounded-circle me-1" src="@Url.Action("UserProfilePicMethod", "UserProfileController",new{id=ViewData["userId"]})" height="24" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

**And in UserProfileController do the action method as follows:**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserProfilePicMethod(string? id)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var profilPicName = user.ProfilePicName;
        if (profilPicName != null)
        {
            //I upload only jpg files. So my method is for jpg.
            //You can customize as per your requirements.
            var ext = ".jpg";
            
            //Get path for your file by path.combine filename+wwwpath+ext
            var fullname = Path.Combine(profilPicName, ext);
            string profilePicPath = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", fullname);
            //return the image file path
            return PhysicalFile(profilePicPath, "image/jpg");
        }
        //If no image exists return a placeholder image
        var profilePicPathNull = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "placeholder.jpg");
        return PhysicalFile(profilePicPathNull, "image/jpg");
    }
```

This is a rough idea of how to return a physical file path. You can customize according to the requirements.

Thanks to @freedomn-m for pointing me in the right direction in the comment section. Really appreciate your time and effort!

Again this is only one way to call user profile images to your layout or pages. There are of course a lot more. This is the solution I used.

Or the easiest way is to use builtin User Manager in Identity like so in your _layout.html:

```
@{
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var profilepicName = user.ProfilePicName;
var profilePicPath = "~/images" + profilepicName ?? "blankProfilePic.jpg";
}
```

and then call the image tag where image required as below:

```
<img class="rounded-circle me-1" src="@profilePicPath")" height="24" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

Comment: RE downvotes (not mine) - these were before your edits adding code as your original was too broad / lacked details.

Comment: @freedomn-m Wasn't sure what people needed to provide a solution. However I,am always ready to provide additional details for problem resolution. Thanks mate!